# Symfony3 entity property not being updated through OneToMany association method

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following classes:

```
class Pedido
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fin;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Estado", mappedBy="pedido", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $estados;

    public function addEstado(\AppBundle\Entity\Estado $estado)
    {
        $estado->setPedido($this);
        $this->estados[] = $estado;
        $this->estado = $estado->getEstado();

        return $this;
    }
}



class Estado
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="estado", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $estado;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pedido", inversedBy="estados")
     */
    protected $pedido;

}
```

But when I call:

```
$pedido = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pedido')->find(18);
$estado = new Estado;
$estado->setEstado('New Estado');
$pedido->addEstado($estado);

$em->flush();
```

The new Estado entity is persisted correctly, but Pedido remains with estado "Old Estado".

I have dumped $pedido pre and post flush and getEstado returns "New Estado", but in the database remains as "Old Estado".

Weird thing is that if I call:

```
    $pedidos = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pedido')->findAll();
    foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
    {
        $estado = new Estado;
        $estado->setEstado('New Estado');
        $pedido->addEstado($estado);
    }
    $em->flush();
```

First $pedido remains with estado "Old Estado", but all the others succesfully get changed to "New Estado".

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I have a PostPersist method that on estado = "Caducado" calls:

```
$pedido->setFin(new \DateTime);
```

That's what making the first $pedido estado property to stay the same, but can't find the reason why

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
$pedido->setFin(new \DateTime);
```

From PostPersist to PrePersist and problem solved, if anyone knows the explanation behind that, please add it below.